# Apache Spark : spark-submit gives java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError exception

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am new to apache spark and trying to play around with it. I have unpacked spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.3 and because it is a pre built version, I didn't have to build it again.

So next what I did is I installed maven, configured maven in the PATH variable.

Then I created a standalone java app similar to [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/quick-start.html) and and ran it using maven with the following command:

```
$ mvn package
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SimpleApp"
```

It worked perfectly and I got the output also.

Then I was trying to run the app using spark-submit utility and ran the following command

```
$ mvn package
$ YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] target/simple-project-1.0.jar
```

Even though the first command builds it perfectly, running the second command gives me this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class SimpleApp$1 has interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Here is the pom.xml of the Java app

```
<project  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <name>Simple Project</name>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <repositories>
         <repository>
            <id>Akka repository</id>
            <url>http://repo.akka.io/releases</url>
         </repository>
      </repositories>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
              <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
              <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
  </project>
```

Kindly help me find the cause of the issue and how to resolve it. Am I missing any step here?

Regards,
Subhankar

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar issue but with version 0.9.1

```
<version>0.9.1</version>
```

Just changed the version to 1.3 in pom.xml and that fixed it.

```
<version>1.3.0</version>
```

Another thing to consider would be go to maven repository

```
cd ~/.m2/repository 
cd org/apache
rm -rf ./spark
```

come back to your project directory and run

```
mvn clean package
```

This will get dependencies again and rebuild the jar file